# What does socket.IPPROTO_TCP do?

Tags: python, sockets

Level: beginner! I am trying to create a RAW socket.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
```

AF_INET=Address Family is internet protocol

Socket type= RAW!

What does the 3rd argument exactly mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument is for specifying the protocol to be used. IPPROTO_TCP is for using TCP protocol. Refer the link given below for an simple-entry level tutorial

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/what_is_socket.htm